# In R, how can I know the maximum amount of memory that a function uses during execution?

Tags: r, memory, memory-profiling

Or is there a way to calculate the maximum amount of memory from a memory profiling method like profvis?

Comment: The "Data" tab of `profvis` shows how much memory each object created requires, but the maximum may vary depending on if and when `gc` gets called, which will vary by system. `profmem::profmem` does give you a total, but the same caveats apply.

Comment: The function `memory.profile` display memory usage by object type. Another way to monitor memory used by your R session is using `memory.size` function. This function is only supported on windows platform (for another platform it returns `Inf` with a warning).

Answer (score 2):

R has a built-in profiler [`Rprof`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/Rprof.html) capable for tracking this:

```
Rprof(filename = "Rprof.out", memory.profiling = TRUE)
```